# При css анимации отключается border-radius

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, css-animation, border

Имеется кнопка:

```
<button class="l radial green"><icon class="l check"><hr><hr></icon></button>
```

она круглая и `overflow: hidden`. При нажатии на неё внутри создаётся элемент и увеличивается, постепенно исчезая, при этом скругление кнопки отключается. Почему?

[Скрин](http://joxi.ru/12MBKXbFOlYdAJ.jpg)
[Исходники](http://vk.com/doc82203151_384294038)

Comment: Я думаю, что вам значительно быстрее помогут, если вы разместите здесь код примера, включая нужные стили и сам элемент, а не просто выложите архив с исходниками.

Comment: это оптимизация анимации, проблема воспроизводится во всех браузерах?

Comment: Нет только в WebKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Придумал фикс, в родитель, у которого стоит `overflow: hidden;`, добавить `position: relative` и `z-index: 0;`